# Custom Spring Security Logout Filter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to de-authenticate a user (kill their session) within my spring security 3.0.5 web app and then send a redirect to another site to notify them of the logout.  Is this possible within spring and if so what is the general approach to performing these tasks?  Thanks!

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler;

import com.dc.api.model.Users;

public class DCSimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler{

    public void onLogoutSuccess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, 
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication)
     throws java.io.IOException,
            javax.servlet.ServletException{
            Users user=null;
            Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (principal instanceof Users) {
                user = (Users) principal;
                if(user.getType().equals(TEST)){
                    response.sendRedirect("LogoutServlet");
                }
            }
            response.sendRedirect("login.html");

}
```

}

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:463)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:74)
    com.dc.api.service.impl.DCSimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess(DCSimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler.java:24)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subclass SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler and override onLogoutSuccess() to do the redirect.

Configure the logout success handler like:

```
<http>
  ...
  <logout success-handler-ref="myLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
</http>
```

Comment: any ideas on why I would get an illegalState on the redirect?

Comment: that usually means some output was sent before the redirect.

Comment: IllegalStateException was caused by calling the redirect twice. `response.sendRedirect("https://secure05.pilot.principal.com/shared/members/corp/LogoutServlet");` and  `response.sendRedirect("/dreamcatcher/auth/login.html");`

Answer (score 8):

Actually the marked "correct answer" is about setting a custom `logout success-handler`, but not `LogoutFilter` , as defining in question.

So, if someone wants to create a custom logout filter, here is a snippet:

```
<bean id="securityContextLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>
<bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout"/>
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="/"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <list>
            <ref bean="securityContextLogoutHandler"/>
            <!--ref bean="myLogoutHandler"/-->
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This is a default filter class with one default predefined handler (this one invalidate session).
If you really need a custom logout filter, then you should change this standard behavior (subclass this or write your own with the same interface).
Also don't forget to register it:

```
    <security:http>
....
        <custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="logoutFilter"/>
    </security:http>
```

**UPDATE**:
After reading some spring code, I found, that there is one more default logout handler - [`RememberMeServices`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.html), defined with the interface `AbstractRememberMeServices implements LogoutHandler`. So if you are using `RememberMeServices` and want to write a custom filter including RememberMe support, you also need add a reference to your `RememberMeServices` in list of logout handlers.